# VBA; Multiplying two ranges with relative reference

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I want to do sumproduct for a range in Column G with a dataset without 5% outliers. First step is that I count the amount of numbers in whole column, sort, multiply with 0.05 and than clear top and bottom 5%. Next step is to set two ranges that multiply (Colmuns C & G).

I know sumproduct is an array formula. Can you help me?

Sub test

```
Sheets.Add.Name = "Data"

Sheets("Worksheet").Select

Dim c As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim w As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim r As Range
Dim s As Range
Dim t As String

c = Worksheets("Worksheet").Range("G:G").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
i = Round(0.05 * c, 0)
w = i + 1
x = i + 2
y = c - i + 2
z = c - i + 1
Set r = Worksheets("Worksheet").Range(Cells(x, 3), Cells(z, 3))
Set s = Worksheets("Worksheet").Range(Cells(x, 7), Cells(z, 7))
```

Range R and s do not work

What I'd like to see is 
    Range("A3").Value = "=Sumproduct(Range(r,s)/SUM(r)".
The last step is to get the weighted average.

I think a simple VBA code, but hard for me to find. 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly qualify all `Range` and `Cells` calls:

```
With Worksheets("Worksheet")
    Set r = .Range(.Cells(x, 3), .Cells(z, 3))
    Set s = .Range(.Cells(x, 7), .Cells(z, 7))
End With
Range("A3").Value = Application.Sumproduct(r, s)/Application.SUM(r)
```